# Prove that every proper rigid motion in space (R^3) that fixes the origin is a rotation about some axis

Tags: geometry, rotations, rigid-transformation

I tried to prove this theorem but having hard time to start with. What I have gotten hint is that starting with rigid motion f = La(left multiplication by A) where A is in O(3) (set of all orthogonal matrices) with det(A)=-1 then using eigenvalue.

Comment: Cubics always have roots, so you always have an eigenvalue.  One has eigenspace dimension 1, which is your axis of rotation.

Comment: @Randall How do you know there is an eigenspace of dimension $1$?

Comment: Use a Gram-Schmidt style argument.  You have a real eigenvalue, so choose a non-zero eigenvector (might as well make it unit).  Expand this to a basis.  The resulting matrix comes in a block which makes it clear.  (I am also assuming the original determinant was 1.)

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I've been assuming that the OP wants to show that every element of $SO(3)$ (besides the identity) has an axis.  True, but not what was asked.  I didn't read all that well.

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v2): Change -1 to +1.

Answer (score 0):

What is a "proper" rigid motion? The map taking $x$ to $-x$ is a rigid motion that fixes the origin, but is not a rotation.